Is there a difference in module creation if I use export * instead of export {Component1, Component2} in my index.ts
I recently ran into a failing test where I received the following error message"
TypeError: Cannot redefine property: getCurrentRouteSnapshot

I read the following StackOverflow and found this could be a result of __esModule being false, leading to the import not being configurable.
jest spyOn not working on index file, cannot redefine property.
While the solution there worked, it felt like a bit of a bandaid fix, and I was curious why __esModule was false in the first place.
My index file that exports that helper function contains the following:
export * from './router.tools';

I looked into my tsconfig.spec.json, which looks like the following:
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "target": "ES2016",
    "types": ["jest", "node", "chart.js"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.spec.ts", "../../types/**/*"]
}

I noticed that "module" was set to "CommonJS".
When I was looking into CommonJS export standards, I wasn't seeing anywhere that would use export *.
How export all variable on commonjs from deferent file in one place
I changed my index.ts to instead export the following (All exports individually):
export {getCurrentRouteSnapshot, GetCurrentApplication, routeToProbeFeature, ApplicationType, MonitorableTab} from './router.tools';

This fixed the failing test.
Why would export * lead to this not being configurable, but export {/*All Modules*/} does not?

My thought was my index.ts was somehow re-defining the export when using export *, when the alternative was just exporting the current definition.

Seems like the module property, should not be commonjs since export * from './router.tools';, so try changing the module property according to the tsconfig.json of your application.
TSConfig Module documentation
You can try the options esnext or es6 or node, but best is to use what you have already in your tsconfig.json.
Sample TSconfig.json:
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "module": "esnext", 
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2016",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    ...
}

Reference Stackblitz
